# cannot determine loading status Error showing in Grid with Chrome and Edge browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, grid

I am working on **Selenium Grid 4.3.0**. Browser Ver: **chrome=103.0.5060.114** Chrome Driver **Ver: 103.0.5060.53** .
Browser is Opening and then crashes only in Chrome and Edge. Firefox works Fine.

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from unknown error: unexpected command response
(Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.114)
Build info: version: '4.3.0', revision: 'a4995e2c09*'
System info: host: 'SW000PALASH', ip: '172.17.12.26', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_202'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Command: [53fe9505a2bce2a09c1ad83cfcc0b657, clickElement {id=339f8a47-f1b6-47a0-93d8-6bb25fcacc55}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 103.0.5060.114, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 103.0.5060.53 (a1711811edd7..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Palashc\AppData\Lo...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:53490}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://172.17.12.26:4444/sess..., se:cdpVersion: 103.0.5060.114, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Element: [[RemoteWebDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (53fe9505a2bce2a09c1ad83cfcc0b657)] -> xpath: //ul[@id='navbar-collapse']//a[@id='stocks-dd']]
Session ID: 53fe9505a2bce2a09c1ad83cfcc0b657
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.TracedCommandExecutor.execute(TracedCommandExecutor.java:51)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:569)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:257)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:78)
at com.zacks.parallel.ParallelDemo.clickStockLink(ParallelDemo.java:81)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:40)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:489)
at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$1.call(ThreadUtil.java:52)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)